# checkin code to subversion from Visual studio 2008 where directory folders at same level solution file is at

Tags: c#, svn, visual-studio-2008

I am using the current version of anksvn. I can add a C# 2008 console application successfully to subversion. I can also download the C# 2008 code to my workstation as a working copy. However the problem is the application does not compile clean. I am getting the error message, `"missing directive or an assembly reference"` on alot of the members.

I know there has to be some kind of a problem when I add this soltuion to 
anksvn. Note: I can load all the other soltuion files  to anksvn and I do not 
have problems.

What is occuring is the 3 other project files that I am working with are at 
the same directory level where the solution file is located at. One of the 3 
project files that I am referring to has its own visual studio 2008 solution also.

I believe most other solution files have their project files in a directory 
path level that is lower than the solution file. 
 One thing  I have tried was to open up the solution file and change the 
directory paths where the 3 files are located at. This did not help. 
 Thus can you tell what I can do when I check in this file to anksvn, so that it 
will compile clean once I have checked it oout of anksvn?